Yolov8 yaml bag
when I try to run yolov8
I get an error that the data.yaml file was not found although this file is there in the photo below, you can see my code
I tried changing the path, renaming the folder, specifying the absolute path to the file
enter image 1 description here
enter image 2 description here

Hello, you're using slashes (/) rather than backslashes (\\) in a Windows path.

On Windows you have to use this slash to define paths: \
I recommend to use os.path.join(folders,separates,by,comma,and,file.extension) instead to make sure your script will run on whatever OS.

i try chang / to \  this not help

Also, you check your data path inside the script. It seems to miss the folder "NN" between "Python" and "Opencvv".
